# How to unselect item in listbox?

Tags: c#, indexing, listbox, listboxitem

If I have a list box is it possible that when I click on item first time it will select it and if I click on it second time it will unselect?

If yes how can I do it?

Comment: what you want is not a list box, it's a check box list. In WPF it is very simple to implement one, in winforms you need to create a panel with vertical scroll enabled and in background code iterate to create check box for each data in that panel and mapping some key to the tag of each check box to be able to know which data the checkbox refers too.

Answer (score 1):

Naturally it is not possible to ordinarily click again to deselect, but their is a way around it. listen to the SelecttionChanged event of the listBox, always get the selectedindex, upon another select set selectedindex to -1